Как сопоставить отправленное сообщение по e-mail и уведомление о его прочтении?
Как сопоставить уведомление о прочтении сообщения с отправленным сообщением?
Самый простой способ - по предмету сообщения. Но некоторые сервисы не возвращают тему, например, mail.ru.
ConversationID и ConversationIndex также mail.ru изменяет и сопоставить невозможно.
Какие есть варианты?
